# Parsing Excel sheet in Hebrew (.xlsx) to JSON produces question marks

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, excel

I'm trying to parse Excel (*.xlsx) to a JSON object in Node JS , however all the columns with Hebrew characters are converted with question marks.

For example :

[image]

Here's the code :

```
"use strict";
const excelToJson = require("convert-excel-to-json");

// -> Read Excel File to Json Data

const excelData = excelToJson({
  sourceFile: "customers.xlsx",
  sheets: [
    {
      // Excel Sheet Name
      name: "Customers",

      header: {
        rows: 1
      }
    }
  ]
});
```

Any idea how to fix it ?

Comment: It could be that the characters are just fine, but your console or text editor can’t render them?

Comment: looks like your package uses this other package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx In the "output" section it says: `"string" string: JS string (characters interpreted as UTF8)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's only your console that's showing invalid characters. Try dumping the excel file contents to file like so:

```
"use strict";
const excelToJson = require("convert-excel-to-json");

// -> Read Excel File to Json Data

const excelData = excelToJson({
sourceFile: "customers.xlsx",
sheets: [
    {
    // Excel Sheet Name
    name: "Customers",

    header: {
        rows: 1
    }
    }
]
});

const fs = require("fs");
fs.writeFileSync("customers.json", JSON.stringify(excelData));
```

Then open in say Notepad++. You should see the Hebrew characters correctly. I'm getting exactly this behaviour. I see invalid characters in the command window, but it's all good when I open the customers.json file.

e.g.

```
{"Customers":[{"A":"לקוח 1"},{"A":"לקוח 2"}]}
```